# In Selenium Webdriver (PHP), how to get index of an element

Tags: php, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium with facebook/WebDriver and phpUnit to make interface tests and I need to get the index of an element relative to its parent element. Currently I'm using a loop that compares the ID of that element to the current one. Is it possible to do it without a loop?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to use the loop. I don't think it can be done without using loop.